# d3.js -- line connecting two transformed svg elements

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I created an array of small circles (dots) laid on a circumference of a larger circle in a loop, with each iteration I rotate the same dot with the same `cx` and `cy` by a different angle using `transform=rotate(i*angle,0,0)`.

Now I want to connect a line between two of the dots, but since each dot has the same `cx` and `cy`, my naive way of passing in the `cx` and `cy` of the two dots as coordinates doesn't seem to work.

Strangely on JSFiddle, half of the line is shown, even though the line's x0 == x1 and y0 == y1: https://jsfiddle.net/8wn30vqn/1/

What is a good way of obtaining the coordinates of a transformed svg element so I can pass them into the line? Or is there some other way I can connect two elements with a line?

Comment: possible to produce an example of what you have ? Perhaps a JSFiddle?

Comment: I've never used JSFiddle.... I'll give it a try!

Comment: So you want to connect a line from the 1st circle to the 2nd, the 2nd to the 3rd and so on ? Or have i misunderstood ?

Comment: It should be dynamically changing based on the JSON data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The good way would be to take transformation matrix from each of your small circles and apply it to the same point to get new point (and then connect these new points).

```
var svgNode = d3circle.node();
var matrix = svgNode.transform.baseVal.consolidate().matrix;

var pt = svgNode.ownerSVGElement.createSVGPoint();
pt.x = 0;
pt.y = 0;
var transformedPoint = pt.matrixTransform(matrix);
... use transformedPoint to create line
```

Comment: Thanks! I was looking for exactly something like this!